# How to get the list of properties of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties

How do I get a list of all the properties of a class?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69496590/how-to-read-custom-attribute-parameters-and-values-attached-to-a-class-or-method) might be also helpful.

Answer (score 1030):

Reflection; for an instance:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

for a type:

```
typeof(Foo).GetProperties();
```

for example:

```
class Foo {
    public int A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
}
...
Foo foo = new Foo {A = 1, B = "abc"};
foreach(var prop in foo.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(foo, null));
}
```

---

Following feedback...

- To get the value of static properties, pass `null` as the first argument to `GetValue`
- To look at non-public properties, use (for example) `GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)` (which returns all public/private instance properties ).

Comment: For completeness, there is also the ComponentModel, exposed by TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(...) - which allows dynamic runtime properties (reflection is fixed at compile-time).

Comment: Suggestion: Expand answer to cover protected/private/static/inherited properties.

Comment: The foreach statement you display even works from within the class you want to get the properties of :)

Comment: It wasn't clear to me from the way the additional comments are stated, but using all 3 flags gets you `internal` properties as well. Maybe I'm the only one who got hung up on the `private`/`non-public` syntax?

Comment: What if that property "A" is another class that also contains properties? I think there should be some kind of a recursive method created. The search would continue until the type of a property is "System", like this: `Type.GetType(innerProp.PropertyType.FullName).Namespace == "System"`.

Comment: When need only properties declared in the current class the ```BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly``` flag can be supplied, for example ```GetProperties(... | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)```

Comment: I get an error saying that `GetProperties()` does not exist.

Comment: @Tadej what framework are you targeting? if you're using .NET core you need to ensure you have the `using System.Reflection` directive and the [`System.Reflection.TypeExtensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions/4.3.0) package referenced - this provides the missing API surface via extension methods

Comment: I can't "install" the System.Reflection.TypeExtensions nuget package. My project is using `.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7`. Is this even possible in a PCL xamarin application?

Comment: @Tadej there do appear to be some `Xamarin` builds of that, but I can't tell you about PCLs; PCLs are notoriously awkward. There should be a *similar* reflection API available - look for `.Properties`, for example.

Comment: BEWARE:  If you don't create a getter, the property won't appear with this method.  For example, if you just declare a property as public (I.e. `public string someProperty;`), and then simply assign values to it, reflection doesn't seem to be useful.  "Fix" that by adding `{ get; }` to the end.  Can others confirm this, please?

Comment: You would do well to wrap that in a Try/Catch block. For example, getting the Length property on a FileInfo object throws an System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Exception unless the subject file exists.

Comment: @HarryPehkonen, I think your example is not a property; it's a field, so you can extract all the info with foo.GetType().GetFields()

Answer (score 123):

You can use **Reflection** to do this:
(from my library - this gets the names and values)

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> DictionaryFromType(object atype)
{
    if (atype == null) return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    Type t = atype.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prp in props)
    {
        object value = prp.GetValue(atype, new object[]{});
        dict.Add(prp.Name, value);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

This thing will not work for properties with an index - for that (it's getting unwieldy):

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> DictionaryFromType(object atype, 
     Dictionary<string, object[]> indexers)
{
    /* replace GetValue() call above with: */
    object value = prp.GetValue(atype, ((indexers.ContainsKey(prp.Name)?indexers[prp.Name]:new string[]{});
}
```

Also, to get only public properties: ([see MSDN on BindingFlags enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(VS.71).aspx))

```
/* replace */
PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
/* with */
PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public)
```

This works on anonymous types, too!
To just get the names:

```
public static string[] PropertiesFromType(object atype)
{
    if (atype == null) return new string[] {};
    Type t = atype.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
    List<string> propNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prp in props)
    {
        propNames.Add(prp.Name);
    }
    return propNames.ToArray();
}
```

And it's just about the same for just the values, or you can use:

```
GetDictionaryFromType().Keys
// or
GetDictionaryFromType().Values
```

But that's a bit slower, I would imagine.

Comment: ... but atype.GetProperty(prp.Name) is going to return prp?

Comment: Regarding the public properties bit, according to the linked MSDN article: "Note   You must specify Instance or Static along with Public or NonPublic or no members will be returned.". So the sample code should be: `t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)` or `t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)`

Comment: wasn't looking for the code, I was looking for an explanation to reflection and wow, so muchly appreciated! Make this generic and you might as well just say your program has super powers ;)

Answer (score 44):

```
public List<string> GetPropertiesNameOfClass(object pObject)
{
    List<string> propertyList = new List<string>();
    if (pObject != null)
    {
        foreach (var prop in pObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            propertyList.Add(prop.Name);
        }
    }
    return propertyList;
}
```

This function is for getting list of Class Properties.

Comment: You might want to change this to use `yield return`. It isn't a big deal, but it's a better way of doing it.

Comment: I like this because it is (almost) the only answer that does not include the word *reflection*.

Comment: But this still **uses** reflection nevertheless.

Comment: i suppose this is much better pObject.GetType().GetProperties().Select(p=>p.Name)

Answer (score 33):

Based on @MarcGravell's answer, here's a version that works in Unity C#.

```
ObjectsClass foo = this;
foreach(var prop in foo.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    Debug.Log("{0}={1}, " + prop.Name + ", " + prop.GetValue(foo, null));
}
```

Answer (score 25):

You could use the `System.Reflection` namespace with the `Type.GetProperties()` mehod:

```
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static);
```

Answer (score 16):

the following code will provide you the list of class properties/attributes/tablecolumns

```
var Properties = typeof(className).GetProperties().Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
var model = new MyObject();
foreach (var property in model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var descricao = property;
    var type = property.PropertyType.Name;
}
```

Comment: This answers the question the OP asked in the most direct way.  6 lines and done.

Answer (score 10):

That's my solution

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }

    public PropertyInfo[] GetProperties()
    {
        try
        {
            return this.GetType().GetProperties();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public PropertyInfo GetByParameterName(string ParameterName)
    {
        try
        {
            return this.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == ParameterName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static MyObject SetValue(MyObject obj, string parameterName,object parameterValue)
    {
        try
        {
            obj.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == parameterName).SetValue(obj, parameterValue);
            return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please.  Please never do this.  This S.O. should do its best to answer a question for the way something SHOULD be done.  If your library requires, or even allows, your strongly-typed objects to be altered using string representations of their member names, there is a huge issue with your code base.  Not to say this wasn't necessary for some scenario where you might obviously have no control over some other part of the system, company politics, or other things.  But this looks like an Architectural Decision, and a horrible one.  This is one decision in a chain of horrible programming choices.

Answer (score 7):

You can use reflection.

```
Type typeOfMyObject = myObject.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties =typeOfMyObject.GetProperties();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is improved @lucasjones answer. I included improvements mentioned in comment section after his answer. I hope someone will find this useful.

```
public static string[] GetTypePropertyNames(object classObject,  BindingFlags bindingFlags)
{
    if (classObject == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(classObject));
    }

        var type = classObject.GetType();
        var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties(bindingFlags);

        return propertyInfos.Select(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name).ToArray();
 }
```

Comment: I guess you can edit his answer for that, not make your own. Basically it would be one less answer to see which gives the same perspective.

Answer (score 2):

I am also facing this kind of requirement.

From this discussion I got another Idea,

```
Obj.GetType().GetProperties()[0].Name
```

This is also showing the property name.

```
Obj.GetType().GetProperties().Count();
```

this showing number of properties.

Thanks to all. This is nice discussion.