# How can a formcollection be enumerated in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enumerator

How can I enumerate through all the key/values of 
a FormCollection (system.web.mvc) in [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework)?

Comment: Further how can we find if the item was returned from a text box or a hidden field or a combo box etc?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to do it specifically with a FormCollection object.

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(FormCollection formCollection)
{
  foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
  {
    var value = formCollection[key];
  }

  foreach (var key in formCollection.Keys)
  {
    var value = formCollection[key.ToString()];
  }

  // Using the ValueProvider
  var valueProvider = formCollection.ToValueProvider();
  foreach (var key in valueProvider.Keys)
  {
    var value = valueProvider[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note: ToValueProvider() changed between framework 3.5 and 4.0

Comment: can i create or [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.add(v=vs.118).aspx) values to `formcollection` from model [properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class) in key value pair ?

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, ValueProviderResult> kvp in form.ToValueProvider())
{
    string htmlControlName = kvp.Key;
    string htmlControlValue = kvp.Value.AttemptedValue;
}
```

Comment: This applies to Framework 3.5 where ToValueProvider returns an IDictionary. In Framework 4.0 ToValueProvider returns an IValueProvider.

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach(var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
   var value = Request.Form[key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
string keyname;
string keyvalue;

for (int i = 0; i <= fc.Count - 1; i++)
{
    keyname = fc.AllKeys[i];
    keyvalue = fc[i];
}
```

hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Framework 4.0, the code to use the ValueProvider is:

```
        IValueProvider valueProvider = formValues.ToValueProvider();
        foreach (string key in formValues.Keys)
        {
            ValueProviderResult result = valueProvider.GetValue(key);
            string value = result.AttemptedValue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

And in VB.Net:

```
Dim fv As KeyValuePair(Of String, ValueProviderResult)
For Each fv In formValues.ToValueProvider
    Response.Write(fv.Key + ": " + fv.Value.AttemptedValue)
Next
```

Comment: I get "Expression is of type 'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider', which is not a collection type" when I try this.  If I leave out the "ToValueProvider" it compiles, but I get "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @DrydenMaker - that is because you are using 4.0. This answer applies to 3.5