# How to loop through the FormCollection to check if textboxes have values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a search page that has 6 textboxes which i pass as FormCollection to the action in the controller. I dont want to search for records if ther is no values in textboxes.

Is there a way to loop through all textboxes in FormCollection to check which ones have values in them?

I am a student in the college and this project is part of my summer experience program. 
I realize that this is a newbie question :)
Thank you!

Comment: A full answer with multiple methods can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762825/how-can-a-formcollection-be-enumerated-in-asp-net-mvc).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can loop through the `FormCollection` like this:

```
foreach( string key in forms.Keys )
{
    ...
}
```

However, note that the browser only sends you names and values. It does not send you the types of inputs, so you have no way to check if the value is a checkbox, unless you know all checkboxes names in advance. But if that's the case, you don't need to loop - just take them out of the collection by name.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>();
for(int i= 0; i< form.AllKeys.Count(); ++i)
{
    list.Add(form.Get(i));
}
```

This will give you all the actual values for each key