# How can a formcollection be enumerated in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0, formcollection

I was previously using [How can a formcollection be enumerated in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762825/how-can-a-formcollection-be-enumerated-in-asp-net-mvc) 's implementation but now I'm on VS2010 and MVC2 its complaining:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.IValueProvider' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary'. An 
explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    C:\~\ProjectMVC\Controllers\TheController.cs    line    ProjectMVC
```

The code is ...

```
IDictionary<string, ValueProviderResult> tmpCollection = collection.ToValueProvider();

for (int j = 1; j <= noprops; j++)
            {
                string shopNmTmp =
                    (from t in tmpCollection
                     where t.Key.StartsWith(j + ".discount.sname." + j)
                     select t.Value.AttemptedValue).First();
                string shopCdTmp =
                    (from t in tmpCollection
                     where t.Key.StartsWith(j + ".discount.sref." + j)
                     select t.Value.AttemptedValue).First();
...
```

Did something change when I wasn't looking; this compiles and works and runs and has no issues in MVC1; but wont compile in 2.

Thanks

#### Update

I techically just fixed this by using:

```
Dictionary<string, string> tmpCollection = collection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, v => collection[v]);
```

instead.

But I'd still be interested in why it changed between versions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I techically just fixed this by using:

```
Dictionary<string, string> tmpCollection = collection.
                                 AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, v => collection[v]);
```

*Linebreak added after collection. for formatting*