# How to use Ajax form when the form is built dynamically?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in my aspx markup.

I add to it some fields dynamically.

I submit them to a controller's action.

How should I read them in the server side ?

**Update**

1. My form contains `n` textboxes.
2. I have thought to use one model that will contain an
   `IEnumerable<FormItem>`

in the client side I'll fill it with Ajax form.

Make sense?

Comment: Have you tried FindControl(controlName)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have thought to use one model that will contain an IEnumerable

Yeah, great idea. So once you have defined the `FormItem` class (depending on your needs) you are ready to roll:

```
public class FormItem
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
<form id="myform" action="/" method="post">
    <!-- Those inputs could be added dynamically -->
    <input type="text" name="[0].Value" />
    <input type="text" name="[1].Value" />
    <input type="text" name="[2].Value" />
    <input type="text" name="[3].Value" />

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

and finally AJAXify the form:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Make sure you checkout [Phil Haack's blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) about the expected wire format for binding to lists.

Steve Sanderson's [blog post post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) about editing a variable length list is also a must read.

Comment: `<% for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { %>` what if I don't know how many forms are there?

Comment: how will the default binder on the server side handle `form.serialize()`? as a `List`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form contains a textbox for the user to enter an e-mail address, and the markup for your form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index"))
{
    <!-- pretend this field was dynamically created with javascript -->
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

The value inside of the `email` textbox can be accessed using the `Form` property of the `Request` object:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Get the value of the input named `email`
        var email = Request.Form["email"];

        /* Do cool stuff because you can */
    }
}
```

Or, you could modify your action method to accepted a string parameter with the same name as the input:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string email)
    {
        // The default model binder will set the value of the `email` parameter to the 
        // value of the matching input from your form

        /* Do cool stuff because you can */
    }
}
```

There are other ways, like accepting a parameter of type [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx) (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762825/how-can-a-formcollection-be-enumerated-in-asp-net-mvc)), or creating a view model class with strongly-typed

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on `new model class`. This is the most interesting, but its dynamic. How whould I fill List on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery, If your fields are being dynamically created then I suppose you would pass those fields as an array.
You should add a class to every new field, so you can fetch them.

```
<input class="dynamicInput" type="text"></input>
<input class="dynamicInput" type="text"></input>
<input class="dynamicInput" type="text"></input>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var myArray = [];
        $('#submit').on('click', function(i,val){
            //It will go through any input with a class "dynamicInput"
            $.each($('.dynamicInput'), function(){
                myArray.push($(this).val());
            });
            //We'll send our array to MyAction
            $.post('/MyController/MyAction', myArray, function(data) {
                //If your action returns a string you could handle it through "data"
                console.log(data);
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Then your action will get this array througn an http post request as a JavaScript object, you will need to deserialize it to a C# array so you can handle it in your server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection values)
{
    var jsonArray = values["myArray"];
    var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var cSharpArray = deserializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(jsonArray);


    //Here you will handle your array as you wish


    //Finally you could pass a string to send a message to your form
    return Content("Message to user");
}
```

Comment: Wanted to do "postback" to save redudant redirect. I redirect to other page anyhow. You have an idea?

Comment: You could have two actions with the same name, one for get request and the other for post request. If you use the jQuery post method, it will do a post request to your post action, the controller will do his job, and then when it finishs, you could handle it in a callback function, without redirect to other url.