# html.beginForm does not call controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have been working on my asp.net mvc 4 for a while now and I have a problem...Actually I have two issues that are related...Let's start with the simple one first.

I have many views and all work except for this one....I have stripped it down and made it simple to try to find the error...but the following is still NOT CALL THE CONTROLLER METHOD:

```
@using TBS.Etracs.Web.Main.Areas.WorkOrder.Models
@model WorkOrderInputModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Work Orders Per Pad";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("StartWorkOrderTask", "Mobile", 
         new {WorkCenterID=Model.WorkCenterID, VIN=Model.VIN })) 
{   
        <div>
        <label><strong>WorkCenterID:</strong></label>
        <label>@Model.WorkCenterID</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label><strong>VIN:</strong></label>
        <label>@Model.VIN</label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Start Work Order" />
}
```

The controller method is a controller classed named "MobileController" and here is the method signature:

```
 [HttpPost]  //Tried with and without this attribute...
 public ActionResult StartWorkOrderTask(int WorkCenterID, string VIN)
    {
    }
```

I have put a break point in the controller method....and it NEVER GETS INVOKED when the input 
button on the form is hit....

I have seen this sort of problem before caused by:
               1) Having more than one beginForm
               2) Not having the right javascript files included
               3) Style parameters ....I don't know why but including style on some 
                          controls have caused the input button not to work...
               4) I am sure I have hit others, but they don't come to mind right now....

I have used firebug to examine the html and I don't see anything wrong...it is creating a form with a dataurl pointing to the method....with the values of WorkCenterID and VIN filled in...what could be causing the probem??????

Does anyone have a suggestion of what to look at or what to try to debug this?

My second issue is also involving the calling of the controller methods.... I know that we should be able to have a method like this:

```
   public ActionResult StartWorkOrderTask(WorkOrderInputModel model)
```

this on the beginForm

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("StartWorkOrderTask", "Mobile"))
```

But about 90% of the time when I do this the controller method does get called....I hit the input button and nothing happens.....by explicitly putting the arguments in the beginForm I "solve" the problem....but I have no idea why the first does not work

I have not defined anything special for the routes...just used the default....I am using areas, but I have been careful on the naming so there is no conflict...

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would have a get and a post, your get will use the same model as your post and can then run like so:

```
public ActionResult StartWorkOrderTask(WorkOrderInputModel model)
```

where workorderinputmodel is your VIEW model, this will allow for the simple:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
```

and you also don't need any custom routes.   However   with

```
public ActionResult StartWorkOrderTask(int WorkCenterID, string VIN)
{
}
```

You would need a custom route like so:

```
routes.MapRoute("Nameforthis", "area/Controller/View/{WorkCenterID}/{VIN}", new { controller = "namehere", action = "namehere" });
```

Notice the properties names inside the string {}   This allows for auto mapping.

Another solutions in to take in a form values collection and pass over no routes values, you can then read the properties of that.

The following link juice may help:  [How can a formcollection be enumerated in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762825/how-can-a-formcollection-be-enumerated-in-asp-net-mvc)

And finally, do you get a 404, or an error, or do your forms simply not submit?
Alos have you checked the rendered HTML to have a look at what the post URL is, that your code has generated.

Comment: I understand what you are saying about the get and post....I do have the get that creates the screen and waits for input....I just did not mention this....I was focused on processing the information from the screen...which is where the post comes in... I expected that I would need to have the [HttpPost] attribute to specify the post, but what I have noticed is that the code seems to work the same with or with the HttpPost which I don't understand...

Comment: (ran out of space)....The other point I am confused about is the routes...I understand what you are saying about the need for custom routes...but the thing that confuses me is the code (USUALLY) works when I convert from the model to the set of primitatve types...I also start with the model and when I have problems convert it to the primitive types (without modifying the routes) ...and the code starts working????? I am not getting any errors...the code just hangs...I hit the button and nothing happens...no controller method is invoked, but no error....Yes I checked the rendered html

Comment: (ran out of space)....anyway the rendered HTML looks good...in the above example it is a simple form that is posting to the controller method public ActionResult StartWorkOrderTask(int WorkCenterID, string VIN)

Comment: have you tried fiddler to just make sure there are no http erros going on, seems strange.  the strangest part being you adding new {WorkCenterID=Model.WorkCenterID, VIN=Model.VIN })  to your html form, but then having the form below too, in essence doubling up your model. As for routes, I always, always use routes if my action takes in anything that is either not a model, formcollection or int id  and i never have issues with posting.

Comment: I haven't used fiddler...but I used firebug and glimpse to view the actually html and I did not see any errors....I will post the firebug output on Monday when I get back to work....thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

I am still clueless about the cause....Here is the output of firebug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ui-mobile">
<head>
<base href="http://localhost:58028/WorkOrder/Mobile/ViewWorkOrdersByPad?WorkCenterID=159">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Work Orders Per Pad</title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<link href="/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Site.Mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Mobile/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.css">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js">
<script>
</head>
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
<div class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" data-theme="c" 
 data-role="page" data-url="/WorkOrder/Mobile/ViewWorkOrdersByPad?WorkCenterID=159"
 tabindex="0" style="min-height: 321px;">role=

"page" theme="c"

mobilePage=Object { element={...}, uuid=1, eventNamespace=".page1", more...}title=

"Work Orders Per Pad"

<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default">
 mobileLoader=Object { element={...}, uuid= 0, eventNamespace=".loader0", more...}
</body>
</html>
```