# How to access Form data when call action method in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my project i have create dynamic control like text box and call action method on button click.In action method i want to access all values for control which is dynamically created.I have used Request.Form but it will return me null value in my case.So please help me how can i achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

you can access form data by Request

> Request["fieldName"]

Answer (score 0):

When you create your form using `@Html.BeginForm`, your action can accept `FormCollection collection`.  Then, you'll have access to all your form control values.

[How can a formcollection be enumerated in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762825/how-can-a-formcollection-be-enumerated-in-asp-net-mvc)

Just create a Test Controller using the wizard "With Read/Write Actions" and review the Create code.  This will show you how it works.