# Getting ALL the properties of an object

Tags: c#

i have object like this:

```
some_object
```

this object has like 1000 properties.

i would like to loop through every property like this:

```
foreach (property in some_object)
//output the property
```

is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-class

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use reflection.

```
// Get property array
var properties = GetProperties(some_object);

foreach (var p in properties)
{
    string name = p.Name;
    var value = p.GetValue(some_object, null);
}

private static PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(object obj)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperties();
}
```

However, this still does not solve the problem where you have an object with 1000 properties.

Comment: what are you using name for?

Answer (score 30):

Another approach you can use in this situation is converting an object into a JSON object. The JSON.NET library makes this easy and almost any object can be represented in JSON. You can then loop through the objects properties as Name / Value pairs. This approach would be useful for composite objects which contain other objects as you can loop through them in a tree-like nature.

```
MyClass some_object = new MyClass() { PropA = "A", PropB = "B", PropC = "C" };
JObject json = JObject.FromObject(some_object);
foreach (JProperty property in json.Properties())
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name + " - " + property.Value);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This is a fantastic and simple solution.  Takes care of all the sub-objects automatically without having to worry about recursion or grabbing all the properties yourself.

Answer (score 8):

```
using System.Reflection;  // reflection namespace

// get all public static properties of MyClass type
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Static);
// sort properties by name
Array.Sort(propertyInfos,
        delegate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo2)
        { return propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name); });

// write property names
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
  Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
}
```

Source: http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/

Comment: The Linq gods are crying right now...

Answer (score 2):

You want one of the following, choose which works best for you:

**Reflection:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/136wx94f.aspx

**Dynamic type:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

though as someone already pointed out, a class with 1000 properties is a code smell. You probably want a dictionary or collection instead,

Answer (score 2):

better version for deep search props also in basetypes

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllProperties(Type t)
{
  if (t == null)
    return Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>();

  BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
    return t.GetProperties(flags).Union(GetAllProperties(t.BaseType));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use reflection.

There's even an article that describes how to do what you want:-

http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2006/11/19/97548.aspx