# Reflection: object is typed assigned

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I get the fields out of the parameter (is of type SomeObject) variable of the Doit-method()?
I cannot change the signature of the Doit method and I cannot use the SomeObject in the Doit method.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Doit(typeof(SomeObject));
    }

    private static string Doit(object parameter)
    {
        var field = parameter.GetType().GetField("MyString");
        return field.GetValue("MyString").ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What is `parameter`?  Is it of type `SomeObject`?  And why can't you use `SomeObject` inside the `Doit` method?

Comment: Does this question give you some needed insight? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445045/c-sharp-getting-all-the-properties-of-an-object\

Comment: Here is a Microsoft reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you passing the Type or are you passing an instance, it makes all the difference.

Comment: Iam passing the type ( Doit(SomeObject) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `parameter` variable is of type `SomeObject`.

Normally, you would simply want to cast inside your method, like this:

```
private static string Doit(object parameter)
{
    var field = ((SomeObject)parameter).GetField("MyString");
    return field.GetValue("MyString").ToString();
}
```

If you truly don't have access to the `SomeObject` type from within that method, you can try using the [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword to allow for late-bound calls.  It will look better than using the Reflection API.  Like this:

```
private static string Doit(object parameter)
{
    var field = ((dynamic)parameter).GetField("MyString");
    return field.GetValue("MyString").ToString();
}
```

But beware, just like using the Reflection API, if you get your method calls wrong when using `dynamic`, the compiler will not be able to help you.  It will fail at runtime.

**EDIT**

If you want to downvote, that's ok, but I do appreciate it when it comes accompanied by a constructive comment.