# Generic solution to compare two generic list and type known only on run time

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have gone through many posts in which this question is answered. But the thing is I have two list that is generic and whose type will be known at run time, secondly i need to compare all the columns of one list to all the column of other list. The only uniform thing is that the two list will be of same type.

And this operation has to be done 27 times for different types of list.

So I need a generic solution to compare the two list. Any further details required please tell. But this is important for me.

```
 private void CompareTwoObjects(IList dataFromExcel, IList dataFromTable)
        {
            foreach (var objExcel in dataFromExcel)
            {

            }
        }
```

Hope fully something like this. I am not sure. May be this could help you get what exactly is needed.

Comment: May be you implement Equals() function for all types and use it?

Comment: I'd think the only possible solution is to use reflection here

Comment: yes I know reflection to be used but how to compare the properties using linq. As I need to compare record of one list with all the records of other. I was thinking to use .Any()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your easiest solution of all would be to implement [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on your 27 different types. Then you can use the regular equals operators (`dataFromExcel.Equals(dataFromTable)` or `dataFromExcel == dataFromTable`. However, if you need to be able to do anything with the values during the process, there are other options you have.

Using an idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8937571/1195056), you can get this without having to use reflection. Utilize the Newtonsoft JSON.NET library to do the "heavy lifting" for you, and keep your code readable.

The one thing you'd want to do is restrict the type of each list to the same type. Your method would look something like this:

```
private bool CompareTwoObjects<T>(T one, T two)
{
    var json1 = JObject.FromObject(one);
    var json2 = JObject.FromObject(two);

    foreach (JProperty prop1 in json1.Properties())
    {
        var prop2 = json2.Properties().First(p => p.Name == prop1.Name);

        if (prop1.Value != prop2.Value)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Seeing in your comment that you want to compare a collection of each, you can still utilize both options.

`IEquatable<T>` method:

```
var allAreEqual = dataFromExcel.All(one => dataFromTable.Any(two => one == two));
```

Custom method:

```
var allAreEqual = dataFromExcel(one => dataFromTable.Any(two => CompareTwoObjects(one, two));
```

I'm sure there's some optimization that you can do here to reduce the N factor, but this points you in the right direction.

Comment: For var allAreEqual = dataFromExcel.All(one => dataFromTable.Any(two => one == two)); i am getting does not contain definition for ALL. In second we are not getting JObject which library to use for this

Comment: @AnirudhAgarwal Your `dataFromExcel` and `dataFromTable` with the `.Any()` and `.All()` methods would need to be the collections of the objects.

Comment: @AnirudhAgarwal The `JObject` library comes from the Newtonsoft JSON.NET library which I mentioned in my answer just before covering that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got the answer with help of your answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this solution (because of perfomance and serializable types) but probably you can serialize collections to JSON(for example) and compare strings. Notice that in this case collections closed by different types like 
`List<TypeForCompare1>()` and `List<TypeForCompare2>()` can be equal with current implementation. Nevertheless it's easy to try maybe it will be enough for you.

```
class Type1
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

class TypeForCompare1
{
    public Type1 Prop1 { get; set; }
    public double Prop2 { get; set; }
}

class TypeForCompare2
{
    public Type1 Prop1 { get; set; }
    public double Prop2 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var List1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
        var List2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

        var List3 = new List<TypeForCompare1>() {
            new TypeForCompare1() { Prop1 = new Type1 { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = "test" }, Prop2 = 1.23 },
        };

        var List4 = new List<TypeForCompare2>() {
            new TypeForCompare2() { Prop1 = new Type1 { Prop1 = 1, Prop2 = "test" }, Prop2 = 1.23 },
        };

        Console.WriteLine(CompareTwoObjects(List1, List2));
        Console.WriteLine(CompareTwoObjects(List3, List4));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static bool CompareTwoObjects(IList obj1, IList obj2)
    {
        var JsonObj1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj1);
        var JsonObj2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj2);
        return JsonObj1 == JsonObj2;
    }
}
```