# Get List of Properties from a Class T using C# Reflection

Tags: c#, properties, system.reflection, type-parameter

I need to get a list of properties from Class `T` - `GetProperty<Foo>()`. I tried the following code but it fails.

Sample Class:

```
public class Foo {
    public int PropA { get; set; }
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the following Code:

```
public List<string> GetProperty<T>() where T : class {

    List<string> propList = new List<string>();

    // get all public static properties of MyClass type
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
    propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                    BindingFlags.Static);
    // sort properties by name
    Array.Sort(propertyInfos,
            delegate (PropertyInfo propertyInfo1,PropertyInfo propertyInfo2) { return propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name); });

    // write property names
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos) {
        propList.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
    }

    return propList;
}
```

I need to get the List of property name

Expected output: `GetProperty<Foo>()`

```
new List<string>() {
    "PropA",
    "PropB"
}
```

I tried lot of stackoverlow reference, but I can't able to get the expected output.

Reference:

1. [c# getting ALL the properties of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445045/c-sharp-getting-all-the-properties-of-an-object)
2. [How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your binding flags are incorrect.

Since your properties are not static properties but rather instance properties, you need to replace `BindingFlags.Static` with `BindingFlags.Instance`.

```
propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

This will appropriately look for public, instance, non-static properties on your type.  You can also omit the binding flags entirely and get the same results in this case.