# Using Reflection to Get Class Property Information returning nothing

Tags: c#, reflection

I have been tasked with updating a large number of records that all have the same data type and want to write this in such a way I don't have to find every class object and do them manually. Therefore, I thought the best way of doing this would be using reflection using `PropertyInfo`.

Prior to asking this question I have looked at the following;

[Getting ALL the properties of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445045/getting-all-the-properties-of-an-object)
[How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/c%23+get+all+class+properties
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=net-5.0

looking at this, suggested I'm on the right approach, but for the life of me Im not getting the results.

The code is as follows

```
void Main()
{
    var propeties =  typeof(MaterialsStructure).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

}

public class MaterialsStructure
{
    public ExistingProposedDescriptionStructure boundariesField;

    public ExistingProposedDescriptionStructure ceilingsField;
}

public class ExistingProposedDescriptionStructure
{

    public string Existing { get; set; }
    public string Proposed { get; set; }
    public bool NotApplicable { get; set; }
    public bool DontKnow { get; set; } 
}
```

The problem is that when I inspect properties it has 0 items in the array, where I would have expected it to have two properties of type `ExistingProposedDescriptionStructure`. I would be grateful if someone could show me where I have gone wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MaterialsStructure` class doesn't have properties, it has fields. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property) for more detail on that. So either do this:

```
var fields = typeof(MaterialsStructure).GetFields();
```

Or change your class:

```
public class MaterialsStructure
{
    public ExistingProposedDescriptionStructure boundariesField { get; set;}
    public ExistingProposedDescriptionStructure ceilingsField { get; set;}
}
```

Now this will work:

```
var propeties = typeof(MaterialsStructure).GetProperties();
```

Comment: Youre right, thank you.  Its been one of those weeks where I have just not had the focus. As soon as I can mark it as an answer I will do (currently have to wait 8 more minutes)

Comment: By the way, you also had another error because you were only looking for static properties which you don't have, so you should have been using the default as above or `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance`

Comment: Ive fixed that now too, but thank you for your kind help in this one :)