# How to get a list of variables in a class in C#

Tags: c#, list, class, variables

How do I get a list of all the variables in a class, to be used in another class to indicate which Variables will and can be changed by it for example. This is mainly for not having to rewrite a enum when some variables are changed or added.

Edit:
I want to create a class that has some stats that can be modified (Main), and another type of class (ModifyingObject) that has a list of all the stats that it can change and by how much. I want to easily get the variables of the main class, and add a list of which variables does the modifying class change. if I have let's say 10 variables for different stats how can I easily list all the stats the ModifyingObject class can change in the Main class.

```
public class Main{

   float SomeStat = 0;
   string SomeName = "name";

   List<ModifyingObject> objects;

   bool CanModifyStatInThisClas(ModifyingObject object){
      //check if the custom object can modify stats in this class
   }

}

public class ModifyingObject{
  ....
}
```

Comment: you should probably show a coded example of what you have tried or what you are attempting to try.. something like this I have the feeling will get closed because you are not being more specific as to what your true needs are.. are you also wanting to use `Reflection`? or `BindingFlag`

Comment: You might want to consider using another data structure or a design pattern if you want to have a "dynamic" enum. But for us to help you, you'll need to be more specific with what you're attempting to do.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *custom object* and *representative class*. All these words are so overloaded that they're easily misinterpreted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use reflection.

Example:

```
class Foo {
    public int A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
}

...

Foo foo = new Foo {A = 1, B = "abc"};
foreach(var prop in foo.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(foo, null));
}
```

From here: [How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-class)

Properties have attributes (properties) `CanRead` and `CanWrite`, which you may be interested in.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx

Your question is a little vague, though. This may not be the best solution... depends heavily on what you're doing.

Comment: doing an Upgrade system in unity. And i have lots of items that change a classes stats. Some may not even change one stat and others may change them all.

Comment: @Simeon I'm confused by your comment. Was this answer helpful or were you looking for something else?

Comment: yes it was with this i can write universal upgrades that work with any class for example that has the name property and it will change that.