# How can I count number of data members at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have following class in c#. How can I count number of data members at runtime?

```
public static class ABC
{
  public static string A;
  public static string B;
  public static string C;
}
```

Bascially, I have to iterate each datamember and pass it to some function one by one which will assign it some value. Thats why I need this.

If its not possible, is there any other way to do same

Comment: @dasblinkenlight- all datamembers are static

Comment: members are not correctly initialized

Comment: _"Bascially, I have to iterate each datamember and pass it to some function one by one. Thats why I need this."_ - are you sure you need reflection and not interfaces? And by "datamember" you mean "[field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx)"?

Comment: what's `public static A` ?

Comment: is there any need of static class and fields ?

Comment: @CodeCaster - By datamember, I mean fields like A,B and C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
var count = typeof(ABC).GetFields().Length;
```

Each element of the array returned by `GetFields` corresponds to a data member. In addition to getting the count, you can further examine each field - get its name, check its type and so on. You can also use `FieldInfo` objects to get and/or set fields of your target class.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/nDiRFC)

Comment: +1 for `.Length` and demo.

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines shall work. Generally you would use reflection for this kind of things.

```
int count = typeof(ABC)
    .GetFields()
    .Count();
```

*@dasblinkenlight* solution is better, because `.Length` performs in `O(1)`, whereas my `.Count()` is `O(N)`.

Side note, I am sure you know this, public fields are evil, consider using properties instead.