# How to get the list of Enum properties of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties, enums

Closely related to [How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class), I've gotten as far as that question goes but I'm interested in knowing which of the returned properties are enumerations. My first (unlikely) guess was along the lines of:

```
foo A;

foreach (var property in A.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (property.PropertyType is Enum)
        //Celebrate
}
```

This did not work. It's valid, but Visual Studio was even able to warn in advance that "The given expression is never of the provided ('System.Enum') type".

To my understanding, C# Enums are wrappers over top of primitive counting types (defaulting with int, but also possibly byte, short, etc). I can easily test to see of the properties are of these types, but that will lead me to a lot of false positives in my search for Enums.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are almost there. Just use

```
if (property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
    // Celebrate
```

In .NET 4.5, you might need to get a TypeInfo object from the property type.

Answer (score 4):

`property` is a `PropertyInfo` object.
`PropertyInfo` doesn't inherit `Enum`, so that can never be true.

You want to check the `PropertyType` – the `Type` object describing the property's return type.

`if (property.PropertyType is Enum)` won't work either, for the same reason – `Type` doesn't inherit `Enum`.

Instead, you need to look at the properties of the `Type` object to see whether it's an enum type.
In this case, you can just use its `IsEnum` property; in the more general case, you would want to call `IsSubclassOf()`.