# How to set CheckListBox itemsSource to all properties of a class object?

Tags: c#, wpf, checklistbox

I am using WPF checkListBox And I want to populate its elements with all properties of the class given below. And I have a class named Person

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Person
    {
        public enum PersonFields
        {
            PersonPermission1,
            PersonPermission2,
        }

        bool _personPermission1;
        bool _personPermission2;

        public bool PersonPermission1
        {
            get
            { 
                return _personPermission1; 
            }
            set
            {
                if (_personPermission1!= value)
                {
                    _personPermission1= value;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool PersonPermission2
        {
            get
            {
                return _personPermission1; 
            }
            set
            {
                if (_personPermission2!= value)
                {
                    _personPermission2= value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to populate a checkListBox with its Properties dynamically. as in given image.
[image: CheckListBox with dynamic properties]

Comment: This may help get you there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class

Comment: Any specific reason you have to do it this way? more common approach is to have only one property that hold values of both `PersonPermission1` & `PersonPermission2`. Then you can bind the ItemsSource to that property

Comment: I do this because I want to set permissions of different persons.

Comment: You can do that by binding `ItemsSource` with `Converter` and using `Reflection` to get all properties. But for checkbox binding to work twoWay, you need to have reference to actual property. If you are sure Person class will have only these two properties, why not to bind it directly with that property?

Comment: Thanx @RohitVats, but I got my answer.

Comment: So you want only property Names to be shown and not there actual values. Then reflection is a way to go. But like I mentioned, it won't work in TwoWay binding. Anyhow, that might not be your need for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I got my answer...

```
chkListBoxPerson.ItemsSource = typeof(Person).GetProperties();
chkListBoxPerson.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

Here chkListBoxPerson is the name of my CheckListBox.

Answer (score 1):

I you really want to get the names of all your properties, you can get a list of them like this:

```
typeof(Person).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Select(prop => prop.Name).ToList(),
```

I noticed you also have a matching inner `enum`, so you could use its values instead:

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(Person.PersonFields));
```

In both cases you'll still need additional code to set property values based on user actions.

I think a better approach would be to have a `Dictionary` of permissions:

```
var personPermissions = new Dictionary<Person.PersonFields, bool>
{
    { Person.PersonFields.PersonPermission1, false },
    { Person.PersonFields.PersonPermission2, false }
}
```

Now you could bind the `Dictionary` to `ItemsSource`, display `Key` and bind `Value` to checkbox.