# Options dialog with search filter

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, dialog

There are a number of programs nowadays that feature an 'options' dialog where it is possible to apply a search filter. Eclipse, for instance, has this feature in its 'preferences' dialog.

I would like some clues/pointers/whatever as to how to implement this in c#.

Thank you all.

For instance (thanks to helrich)

[image]

Comment: are you referring to the common control for file save/open?

Comment: @MarcoA. I think OP is referring to [this.](http://i.imgur.com/53NuXhV.png)

Comment: In winforms you have powerful `PropertyGrid` control. You can wrap your object into `ICustomTypeDescriptor` to display only properties, which names are matching filter. Try googling, perhaps [`this`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2138/Globalized-property-grid) will do.

Comment: @Sinatr. I can see using how a grid could do. But it is a less desirable option, a workaround. The fact is that some folks are somehow searching through strings in the resources files (?) and then selecting the appropriate pages from there. No clue how, though.

Comment: You can use reflection to get list of properties of your configuration class. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/737151/1997232). Once you have a list - you can apply filter to it, but you will have all problems what `PropertGrid` solves: presenting data (including nested data), editors, validations.

Comment: That's clever. Thanks, Sinatr.