# Get a List of properties from a class and reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties

I am trying to find out how to list the properties of a class that is in a session variable, and having no luck

i know that i can instance the class like so in a generic handler

```
IAdvanceUser user = context.Session["advUser"] as IAdvanceUser;
```

or like this in an aspx

```
IAdvanceUser user = new.SunGardHE.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser();
```

but i can seem to get reflection to work from this SO [How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)

```
IAdvanceUser user = new.SunGardHE.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser();
foreach(var prop in user.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(user, null));
}
```

it doesnt error, but doesnt show any output either

Comment: Your object `user` is of type `IAdvanceUser`, Your code would only show you the properties exist in the interface, and I think you don't have any in your interface. If you need class properties then store/cast the object to your class type and then use reflection.

Comment: Try `foreach(var prop in new.SunGardHE.WebFramework.Security.AdvanceUser().GetType().GetProperties())`

Comment: gives the error CS1031: Type expected

Comment: @JayRizzi there is nothing wrong with the code you posted as long as there are public properties. Create a small test application with a dummy POCO or try different types. @Habib, `user` is still an instance of `AdvanceUser`. Calling `user.GetType()` will return `AdvanceUser`, not `IAdvanceUser`.

Comment: there are public as well as private properties, oh well, whatya gonna do