# Auto generate textboxes for properties with public set C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, treeview

I want to be able to bind a listbox, Treeview or some control to a ObservableCollaction>SomeObject>() and then auto generate textboxes to all properties with a public set within SomeObject. That way I dont have to add or remove any code in WPF if someone remove or add a new property to SomeObject.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction or tell me if this is a stupid idea?

//Max

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should use ObservableCollection for that. That's used when you want to present a collection that will be modified in runtime (i.e. having elements added, removed or modified). Do you expect `SomeObject` properties names to be modified at runtime?

If you just want to expose the names of the properties and their values, use Reflection. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class). Add some behind code to create a collection of pairs with names and values. That should do the trick

Then use some DataTemplate to create the textboxes from this info. I find this [tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/) very useful

Comment: I manage to solve my problem with help from [this](https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/view-object-properties-in-wpf-treeview/). I added a CanWrite property to ObjectNode and then I used DataTemplateSelector to separate the properties with private set from the ones with public set. Then i subscribe to propertychanged on the NodeObject to convert the changed values back to the original object.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/view-object-properties-in-wpf-treeview/) to solve my problem