# Getting a list of attributes and its type of class

Tags: c#, reflection

I pretty sure that this problem has been solved previously here but I do not know even the suitable keyword to search for.

Is it possible in C# to get list of a class or struct attributes and their types in run-time?

P.S. the struct is defined with `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` if this makes difference.

### Edit

I found this [How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)

now the **question** is : does `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` makes any difference ?

Comment: thanks.. it helps me to find this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the attributes by using [Type.GetCustomAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kff8s254(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var attributes = typeof(MyType).GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Comment: and there is no problem with the sequential ?

Comment: No there is no problem.