# Getting properties of derived type on a Gameobject

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, unity-game-engine

So i have several gameobjects in me scene which represent different actors. Also, I have scripts to for each type of actor, and they all derive from `Actor` script.

```
public class Actor : MonoBehaviour {

//some properties

}

/// 

public class Doctor : Actor {

//some more properties 

}
```

only the derived scripts are attached to the gameobjects. i.e. if i have a doctor gameobject- only the `Doctor` script is attached to it in the inspector.

My code runs through all these actor gameobjects- and updates their properties (base + derived) from some data input. 
Currently im checking every gameobject if he has the specific component and then get the properties from the right script.

My objective is to ALWAYS get the properties declared by derived class from `Actor`, that is currently attached to the gameobject, without looking for the component. 
I would think something in Linq will do the trick.

Comment: Not clear. Doctor adds some new properties extending Actor, and you want to get only those defined by Doctor?

Comment: [use reflection to get a class' properties](http://stackoverflow.com/a/737156/2140173)

Comment: basically yes. @OguzOzgul. So i want to crosscheck if a component is fulfilling 2 things: 1- being attached to the game object and 2- being derived from actor

Comment: You should use reflection and the appropriate BindingFlags. If you already implemented getting all the properties, you can just check the PropertyInfo.DeclaringType. If it is Actor, skip. If it's not and it extends Actor, update.

Comment: This would almost work but actor itself is a MonoBehaviour, so i will get the properties of every type except 'actor'.

Comment: What about `obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)`? This will return all properties of the _deepest_ type. Maybe you need some base types. In that case you can use `obj.GetType().BaseType` and call it again using `DeclaredOnly`. This should solve your problem and I think that is what @OguzOzgul meant by _You should use reflection and the appropriate BindingFlags_.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want `GetComponent<Actor>()`, `GetComponents<Actor>()`, or `FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Actor))`.

- `GetComponent` searches a single GameObject and returns the first matching component, or null if no such component is found.
- `GetComponents` searches a single GameObject and returns an array of all matching components, or an empty array if no such components are found.
- `FindObjectsOfType` searches the entire scene and returns an array of all matching Unity objects, or an empty array if no such objects are found. This last call is fairly expensive, but full-scene searches do have their uses.

Searching for `Actor` components will also find `Doctor` components, because every `Doctor` is by definition an `Actor`.

Comment: The thing is i got several actor types derived from 'actor'. When i find 1 i dont want to check which type it is, i want to get a list of the properties immediately. As long as it is derived from 'actor' and attached to a gameobject- i want its properties. With GetComponent i need to specify the component which properties i want to get.

Comment: That sounds like an unusual design choice, but you can [use reflection to get all properties of an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class).