# How to get the configuration property name out of a ConfigurationElementCollection

Tags: c#

I am currently stuck into the problem of how to get all configuration properties out of the ConfigurationElementCollection object. In this post I have printed out the sources for the customized config-file and also the sources for the config-class, which handles the access to the given customized config-file.

```
    configuration>
        configSections>
            section name="Section1" type="MyProject.Section1, Section1" />
        /configSections>
        Section1>
        Section1FieldDefinitions>
            add id="1" project="Proj1" browsername="Order1"/>
            add id="2" project="Proj2" browsername="Order2"/>
            add id="3" project="Proj3" browsername="Order3"/>
        /Section1FieldDefinitions>
    /Section1>
    /configuration>
```

*Source of project.config file. I had to remove the xml open bracket because I was not able to post that code with open brackets.*

---

```
public class Section1 : ConfigurationSection
{
    public const string SectionName = "Section1";

    private const string FieldDefinitionsCollectionName = "Section1FieldDefinitions";

    [ConfigurationProperty(FieldDefinitionsCollectionName)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(Section1Collection),
        AddItemName = "add",
        ClearItemsName = "clear",
        RemoveItemName = "remove")]
    public Section1 Items
    {
        get
        {
            return (Section1Collection)base[FieldDefinitionsCollectionName];
        }
    }
}

public class Section1Collection : ConfigurationElementCollection 
{
    public Section1Collection()
    {
    }

    public Section1FieldDefinitionsElement this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return (Section1FieldDefinitionsElement)BaseGet(index);
        }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            BaseAdd(index, value);
       }    
    }

    public void Add(SectionFieldDefinitionsElement pSection1)
    {
        BaseAdd(pSection1);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        BaseClear();
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new Section1FieldDefinitionsElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((Section1FieldDefinitionsElement)element).ID;
    }

    public void Remove(Section1FieldDefinitionsElement pSection1)
    {
        BaseRemove(pSection1.ID);
    }

    public void Remove(string name)
    {
        BaseRemove(name);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        BaseRemoveAt(index);
    }
}

public class Section1FieldDefinitionsElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("id", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["id"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["id"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("project", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Project
    {
        get 
        {
            return (string)this["project"]; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            this["project"] = value; 
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("browsername", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Browsername
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["browsername"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["browsername"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

*Source of config class*

---

What I currently need is a solution where I can iterate through all Section1FieldDefinitions and get the field names and the field values out the configuration properties. For example - we have three configuration elements - id, project and browsername. I need these three properties by name and value.

Comment: Try posting some actual code

Comment: Please provide your code, your effort, and your expected result.

Comment: Okay. I had problems to add the source code to the post. But now everything should be in. As I wrote, I need the Configuration properties out of the class Section1FieldDefinitionsElement (id, project and browsername including the given values in the config file)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use reflection to list all properties.
Like this:

```
var obj = new Section1FieldDefinitionsElement();
foreach(var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1} ({2})", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(obj, null), prop.Module.Name);
}
```

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/737156/1038933) may provide more information.