# Linq - Get the Static class constants as List

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Here is my static class holding the constants

```
public static class Files
{
    public const string FileA = "Block1";
    public const string FileB = "Block2";
    public const string FileC = "Block3";
    public const string FileD = "Block6.Block7";
 }
```

By any chance, is it possible to get constants as list using LINQ other than converting it to data tables and retrieve. Thanks

Comment: you can use reflection to read the class properties

Comment: Can you please give me sample code. Apologies i have never used reflections

Comment: i think your question is a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class

Comment: Hi! Considering 'converting it to data tables and retrieve' maybe you should better use Enum?

Comment: No. I need it as list and achieve by LINQ. The above link you mentioned has used reflection only. @hpfs

Comment: @IDeveloper: I do not want to convert it as datatable (I have achieved using data table and that perfectly works fine). Just keen to know any other way without data table.

Comment: What makes you think this has anything to do with data tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that you are looking for something like this :

```
List<string> staticconstList = new List<string>(); 
Type type = typeof(Files);
foreach (var field in type.GetFields())

{
    var val = field.GetValue(null);               
    staticconstList.Add(val.ToString());
}
```

Or something like This:

```
List<string> staticconstList = type.GetFields().Select(x => x.GetValue(null).ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the expected type of the output? List of what?

Answer (score 2):

With reflection you can go like this, the result a enumerable with a Field, Value structure.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public static class Files
    {
        public const string FileA = "Block1";
        public const string FileB = "Block2";
        public const string FileC = "Block3";
        public const string FileD = "Block6.Block7";
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var t = typeof(Files);
            var fields = t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

            var list = fields.Select(x => new {Field = x.Name, Value = x.GetValue(null).ToString()});


            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```