# Dynamic if Condition from any class In Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dynamic, conditional-statements

I want to create a dynamic conditional statement.

```
class Condition
{
    targetObject;   //Class or Struct or anythings..
    targetMemberVariable;  //the Member in targetObject

    conditionFilter;
    //It depends on the type of targetMemberVariable.
    //targetMemberVariable is Float type,
    //then conditionFilter automatically becomes a Float type. 
    //No need to change it in "Inspector"

    comparisonValue;
    //This is based on the type of conditionFilter.
    //If it is a float type, the "Inspector" takes a float as its value.

    Public bool CheckCondition(object targetObject)
    {
        //It checks with the above information and returns a true value.
        return true or false;
    }
}
```

I want to get the Unity Editor or C # library keywords.

The intention is to create something like the above.

1. Interactive elements in the game are likely to change.
2. In-game elements can be expanded or added.
3. I do not want to modify conditional statements for each change or extension.

example

[ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCziE.jpg)
[ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b2Sd.jpg)
I remember seeing the library used in dynamic compilation in C # or after adding classes during execution.

Of course I know that dynamic is not universal.
I want to do something like the validation of StarCraft Galaxy Editor.

Here is a game example

```
[Bleeding shot]
Give 10 damage to enemies.
If the enemy's Health is below 20, it adds 10 damage.

unit,health,amount,<=(below)
true-> adds 10 damage.
false -> none.


[Hooking]
If the enemy is enemy, it gives 5 damage and pulls to the front.
If the target is ally, pull to the front and reduce cooldown to 5 seconds.

unit,Tag,Enemy(enum),==
true-> 5 damage and pulls to the front.
false-> pull to the front and reduce cooldown to 5 seconds.

[Healing the Moon]
Heal the target by 10.
If the current time is night, heal 10 more.

GameTimer,DayNight(Enum),Night,==
true->heal 10 more.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making this generic would probably help since the type being tested varies. This way your `CheckCondition` method is type safe.

You could start with just the interface. Down the road you might want a condition that's more complex than just comparing a particular member to some threshold.

```
public interface ICondition<T>
{
    bool CheckCondition(T subject);
}
```

I suspect that in most cases you'll find it easier to just check the condition explicitly than to store member information in the class an use reflection.

For example,

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class MinimumValueCondition : ICondition<SomeClass>
{
    public bool CheckCondition(SomeClass subject)
    {
        return subject.Value > 5;
    }
}
```

It's really easy to read, no reflection required. If some data required to evaluate the condition is variable, you could pass it in.

```
public class MinimumValueCondition : ICondition<SomeClass>
{
    private readonly int _minimumValue;

    public MinimumValueCondition(int minimumValue)
    {
        _minimumValue = minimumValue;
    }

    public bool CheckCondition(SomeClass subject)
    {
        return subject.Value >= _minimumValue;
    }
}
```

You could also write a condition that takes a function as an argument.

```
public class Condition<T> : ICondition<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _conditionFunction;

    public Condition(Func<T, bool> conditionFunction)
    {
        _conditionFunction = conditionFunction;
    }

    public bool CheckCondition(T subject)
    {
        return _conditionFunction(subject);
    }
}
```

That way you could create a `Condition` from an expression or method.

```
var notZeroCondition = new Condition<SomeClass>(subject => subject.Value != 0);
var someOtherCondition = new Condition<SomeClass>(SomeEvaluationMethod);
```

Comment: can i get this information? >>> 'SomeClass.GetPropertiesList'  arrayList or anyList of information about Members.

Comment: Are you asking for details about `SomeClass`? It's just a class I made up for the example. Or are you asking something else - I don't understand.

Comment: for example: Class Unit has [int] Health, [int] Atk, [bool] isAttack. in Code 'Unit.GetGetPropertiesList()'. then i can get informationsCollection in Array.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following - is that part of this question or a different question about how to list the properties of a type?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
I got the keyword without any questions while the questions were coming and going.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class

Comment: I wanted to make a conditional comparison without using a kind of switch statement or if statement. Like a generic.