# How to extract object content in C# without using Json

Tags: c#, .net, object, generics, collections

I need sample code for below issue.
How to Extract the Object information/Content in C# without using JSON. If Object is complex object.We want to extract the object information at runtime. Object content  unknown generic type,String,Primitive,property etc.How to check the depth level of object.?

Answer (score 0):

Cast your JSON text to `JObject` instance in the Json.NET lib, then you can traverse through all properties and analyze them. Look at the following code:

```
string json = "{\"name\" : \"Jim\", \"age\" : 20}";
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Otherwise, if you want to examine a `System.Object` then use reflection. Look for reference documentation on `Type` class

Answer (score 0):

Consider reflection to get all the properties of an object.  For complex types you will need to iterate your way through, reflecting each one and counting the levels.  Check this post to get started - [Properties from a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)