# BindingFlags - get all of them (maximum members)

Tags: c#, reflection

I tried to get all kind of BindingFlags (in order to get all properties):

```
BindingFlags ALL_BF =    BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.ExactBinding |  BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy |  BindingFlags.GetField |  BindingFlags.GetProperty |  BindingFlags.IgnoreCase |  BindingFlags.IgnoreReturn |  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |  BindingFlags.NonPublic |  BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding |  BindingFlags.Public |  BindingFlags.PutDispProperty |  BindingFlags.PutRefDispProperty | BindingFlags.SetField |  BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.SuppressChangeType ;
```

however, this returns empty collection:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties( ALL_BF );
```

when I tried:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public );
```

that returned many members.

1 Can someone explain why first method didnt return result? Which one interferes with other one?

2) Which combination I should use, to get ALL (obtainable) members?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try this:

```
//All actual properties:
obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
//or
obj.GetType().GetProperties((BindingFlags)60);

 //All binding flags (if really needed):
obj.GetType().GetProperties((BindingFlags)(-1));
```

As you can see, it's not the same. The reason is that the BindingFlags "filters" result both explicitly and implicitly (inverted if so). That said, if you want maximum members you should pass some basic inclusive "request" BindingFlags like Public and Instance and avoid exclusive "postfilter" BindingFlags like DeclaredOnly (excludes inherited members).

### Explanation:

It's *binding* flags, so you most likely need *none* of them. I guess you think of:

```
GetMembers(); //Simple way described in MSDN but just syntactically equivalent
```

BUT! Unfortunately, parameterless version returns only public members for some reason. Then, assuming you need to pass binding flags anyway (in variable, etc.), you'll probably want:

```
GetMembers((BindingFlags)0); //but it's like passing BindingFlags.Default
```

Not so obvious, but 0 means "Nothing" (which is BindingFlags.Default), not zero BindingFlags. Then what? Maybe:

```
GetMembers((BindingFlags)(-1));
```

Then you suddenly got all the BindingFlags! But not all the members (probably none at all), because they were *bound*.

Apparently, BindingFlags works like switchable filters: if not specified, it's vice versa (e.g. corresponding members are discarded from the end result). So finally, you need to pass most generic of them. This will be enough for most purposes:

```
GetMembers(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
//or
GetMembers((BindingFlags)60); //just a sum of int representations of these flags
```

> Why -1 returns all the flags?
>
> ---
>
> You need to use `-1` because its binary representation is `...11111111` (for example -2 is `...11111110` etc.), which means that all of its bits are "true". This is the same like using bitwise OR ([Bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)) with every `BindingFlags` constant. You can see it for yourself by using:
>
> `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(-1, 2)); //-1 is the converted value(can be variable); 2 means converting to binary`
>
> After this you only need to convert the resulted value to `BindingFlags` as `GetMembers`-like methods accept only this type.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, please don't yield, and be more clear with your answer.

Comment: years passed, but I've returned to this answer to remind it :) thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

The combination of
`BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic` used in `GetProperties(...)` should be enough.
You may want to add `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` depending on your use-case.

(For fast debugging I use `((BindingFlags)62)` to create the mentioned combination.)

Comment: what's `62` can you explain?

Comment: It is just the combination of the mentioned flags. `Console.WriteLine((BindingFlags)62);` yields `DeclaredOnly, Instance, Static, Public, NonPublic`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you mean by "maximum members"

I recently needed to get ALL members of a type, that is:

- fields - public/private/static/inherited
- properties - public/private/static/inherited which do not have backing fields already included above

Here is a solution for that (we need to recourse up the type hierarchy as GetMembers does not return base private fields):

```
static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetMembers(Type type, bool getStatic=true, bool getPrivate=true, bool getBases=true) {
    var memberList = ImmutableList<MemberInfo>.Empty;
    if (type is null || type == typeof(Object)) return memberList;

    var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public;
    if (getStatic) bindingFlags |= BindingFlags.Static;
    if (getPrivate) bindingFlags |= BindingFlags.NonPublic;

    memberList = memberList.AddRange(type.GetMembers(bindingFlags));
    if (getBases) memberList = memberList.AddRange(GetMembers(type.BaseType, getStatic, getPrivate, getBases));
    return memberList.Where(memberInfo => memberInfo is PropertyInfo || (memberInfo is FieldInfo && memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>() == null)); // filter out property with backing fields
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank. btw, why you are returning if  `Object` type?

Comment: that's the end (top) of the recursion

Comment: btw, does this differ from this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50248686/how-get-private-properties-of-class-baseclass

Comment: similar I guess, you have to loop/recurse if you want base private members

Comment: can you tell,  why do you use `ImmutableList` in the example, and if you can give an alternative example to achieve the same in net framework 4.5+  (maybe with List or whichever best suits).

Comment: @T.Todua I always prefer the immutable containers if possible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try:

```
obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
```

See this question:
[How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)

Comment: that only returns publi.