# How get private properties of Class/BaseClass?

Tags: c#, reflection

I use this code:

```
BindingFlags flags= BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;

PropertyInfo prop =  myObj.GetProperty("Age", flags);
```

`prop` is not null. However, when I try to get all properties from `myObj`:

```
foreach(MemberInfo e in myObj.GetType().GetMembers( flags) ) {    //neither GetProperties helps
    Console.WriteLine(e.Name);
}
```

that property (`Age`) is not listed. I can't understand how this happens.

Comment: Can you show the type declaration for the type of of `myObj`

Comment: I would like to see a minimal example.

Comment: How is Age property declared ?

Comment: `obj` is not `myObj`- or is that a typo? Can you show a single snippet full (minimal) example that shows this behavior?

Comment: Please, show us the class of your object myObj

Comment: @lc. sorry, thats type

Comment: @Sweeper I dont have access to that dll, which defines that.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann same comment as above.

Comment: @Oilid same comment as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dfiference between `Type.GetProperty` and `Type.GetMembers` is that both return private properties/members(which include properties), but `GetMembers` only of this type and not from base types whereas `GetProperty` also returns private properties of base types.

[`GetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic` to include non-public properties (that
>   is, private, internal, and protected properties) in the search.

[`GetMembers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2w5ey1e(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic` to include non-public members (that is,
>   private, internal, and protected members) in the search. Only
>   protected and internal members on base classes are returned; private
>   members on base classes are not returned.

So i guess that `Age` is an inherited property. If you would add `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` the result should be the same, you wouldn't see `Age`.

If you want to force `GetMembers` to include also **private** members of base types, use following extension method that loops all base types:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static MemberInfo[] GetMembersInclPrivateBase(this Type t, BindingFlags flags)
    {
        var memberList = new List<MemberInfo>();
        memberList.AddRange(t.GetMembers(flags));
        Type currentType = t;
        while((currentType = currentType.BaseType) != null)
            memberList.AddRange(currentType.GetMembers(flags));
        return memberList.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Now your `BindingFlags` work already and even a private "inherited" `Age` property is returned:

```
MemberInfo[] allMembers = myObj.GetType().GetMembersInclPrivateBase(flags);
```

Comment: @T.Todua: edited my answer to show you how, use `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`

Comment: so, I cant force `GetMembers` to get all things like `GetProperties` ?

Comment: Flatten Heirarchy only effects  static members, not instance ones. Your msdn quote says as much.

Comment: @T.Todua: i have edited my answer to provide a working solution. `FlattenHierarchy` doesn't help with private members in base types.

Comment: 1) So, your extension method is useful if I use `GetMembers()`, but if I use `GetProperties()`, then it can access private members of base class, without using those hassle and extra codes, right?  However, thanks again, I'll use this code.

Comment: @T.Todua: it changes in the loop head: `while((currentType = currentType.BaseType) != null)`. An assignement returns the assigned value

Comment: @T.Todua: and yes, if you only serach properties you can use `GetProperties`. Note that `GetMembers` also returns fields(even backing fields of properties) and events.