# Checking if Object has null in every property

Tags: c#, null

I have class with multiple properties;

```
public class Employee
{
    public string TYPE { get; set; }
    public int? SOURCE_ID { get; set; }
    public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }        
    public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }

    public List<Department> departmentList { get; set; }
    public List<Address> addressList { get; set; }

}
```

sometimes this object return me with value in any property say

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.FIRST_NAME= 'abc';
```

remaining values are null. This is OK

But, How do I check when **all values** in properties of objects are null

like `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` for object ?

curretly I am checking like this;

```
if(emp.FIRST_NAME == null && emp.LAST_NAME == null && emp.TYPE == null && emp.departmentList == null ...)
```

Comment: Your object has 6 properties - one of them is not even nullable - which makes 5. You're better off just checking each for null than some complex reflection-based scenario. The way you're doing it is arguably the *right* way.

Comment: What about creating a function in your class that does this for you? So you call it whenever you need it.

Comment: Your current check is both relaiable and readable. You may want to split it up over multiple lines (one check per line) even if it is only huge condition. Also a few versions ago they added null-conditional operators to C#6. Those might be a better option for single line checks. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators

Comment: `like string.IsNullOrEmpty() for object ?` Just to clarify what _could be_ a misunderstanding here: an object that is `null` is not the same as an object whose properties are all `null`. If you don't distinguish between the two, you're going to face a lot of misunderstandings whenever you talk about your code.

Comment: @Flater there is lot misunderstanding about that, could you suggest any good readings

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## EDIT

This answer has received some votes in the last time, so I decided to improve it a little, adding simple caching so that `ArePropertiesNotNull` does not retrieve the properties every time it is called, but rather only once for every type.

```
public static class PropertyCache<T>
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IReadOnlyCollection<PropertyInfo>> publicPropertiesLazy
        = new Lazy<IReadOnlyCollection<PropertyInfo>>(() => typeof(T).GetProperties());

    public static IReadOnlyCollection<PropertyInfo> PublicProperties => PropertyCache<T>.publicPropertiesLazy.Value;
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool ArePropertiesNotNull<T>(this T obj)
    {
        return PropertyCache<T>.PublicProperties.All(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(obj) != null);
    }
}
```

(Old answer below.)

---

You could use reflection as proposed by [Joel Harkes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50128845/7571171), e.g. I put together this reusable, ready-to-use extension method

```
public static bool ArePropertiesNotNull<T>(this T obj)
{
    return typeof(T).GetProperties().All(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(obj) != null);    
}
```

which can then be called like this

```
var employee = new Employee();
bool areAllPropertiesNotNull = employee.ArePropertiesNotNull();
```

And now you can check the `areAllPropertiesNotNull`  flag which indicates whether all properties are not null. Returns `true` if all properties are not null, otherwise `false`.

---

## Advantages of this approach

- It doesn't matter whether or not the property type is nullable or not for the check.
- Since above method is generic, you can use it for any type you want and don't have to write boilerplate code for every type you want to check.
- It is more future-proof in case you change the class later. (noted by [ispiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939213/ispiro)).

## Disadvantages

- Reflection can be quite slow, and in this case it is certainly slower than writing explicit code as you currently do. Using simple caching (as proposed by [Reginald Blue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5753629/reginald-blue) will remove much of that overhead.

<sub>In my opinion, the slight performance overhead can be neglected since development time and repetition of code are reduced when using the `ArePropertiesNotNull`, but YMMV.</sub>

Comment: Reflection is also more future-proof in case you change the class and forget to change the testing method.

Comment: so... what's typically slow about reflection is the part where you're trying to find all of the properties (or whatever).  If this is something that's needed to be done a lot, caching the properties into an array will speed it up considerably.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Sure.

Comment: `All(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(obj) != null)` would only return true if **all** properties are **not** null. An object with all null properties would render the same result (false) as an object with only a single null property (false), which is not the point of the test as per OP's description. I assume you either mean `Any(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(obj) != null)` or `! All(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(obj) == null)` (notice the inversion on the second one)

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow please edit the answer from `.Any` to `.All`  so I mark this as accepted, and I assume that `.GetValue()` needs two parameters, `.GetValue(obj, null)`.

Comment: @trighati please see the edited answer. Also, while there exists the `PropertyInfo.GetValue(object, object)` overload, I chose to go with [`PropertyInfo.GetValue(object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx) so that I don't have to pass `null`. Of course you can use either, its completely up to you and will make no difference whatsoever. Thank you for marking this as accepted.

Answer (score 9):

Either you do this by writing down the code to check every property manually (best option) or you use reflection (read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection))

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
var props = emp.GetType().GetProperties())
foreach(var prop in props) 
{
   if(prop.GetValue(foo, null) != null) return false;
}
return true;
```

example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/737156/1275832)

Note that int cannot be null! and its default value will be 0. thus its better to check `prop == default(int)` than `== null`

## option 3

Another option is to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification).

On a change set a boolean field value `isDirty` to true and than you only need to check if this value is true to know if any property has been set (even if property was set with null.

Warning: this method every property can still be null but only checks if a setter was called (changing a value).

Comment: They have `int?`, not `int`.

Comment: @trighati alright, but still you might forget to make all properties nullable.

Comment: @JoelHarkes such as ?

Comment: @trighati int decimal arrays floats structs etc.