# C# GetProperties() doesnt return all of them

Tags: c#, reflection

I have these classes

```
class Foo () {
 public string propA;
 public Bar propB
}

class Bar {
 public string propC;
}
```

When I am trying `Foo.GetType().GetProperties()` it only returns propA.

What am I missing here;

Comment: "I doubt it"..? Especially as  *neither* are properties. Maybe that's not the *actual* Assembly / code being inspected with Reflection?

Comment: @user2864740 What do you mean that neither are properties?

Comment: They are both *fields*. Fields are not returned by `GetProperties`.

Comment: You have no _properties_. Foo has 2 _fields_, and Bar has 1 _fields_.

Comment: I didn't knew there was a difference , thank you guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand difference between Field and Property, there's a good explaination in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/295109/929910

And your example also looks odd, because GetProperties should return 0 results as your class only has fields and not properties.
Proper example would look like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var props = typeof(Foo).GetProperties();
}
class Foo {
    public string propA;
    public Bar propB;
}
class Bar
{
    public string propC;
}
```

And props would contain 0 elements.
But if you would call

```
    var fields = typeof(Foo).GetFields();
```

fields would contain both fields propA and propB.

Answer (score 3):

Your class currently contains fields, not properties.

Field example:

```
private string _myField;
```

Property examples:

```
public string MyField {get;set;}
public string MyField { get { return _myField; } set { _myField = value; } }
public string MyField => _myField;
```

Because they are different things, there are different methods to reflect them. You can either get fields and properties separately:

```
foreach (var field in type.GetFields())
{

}

foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
{

}
```

or you can get "members" and for each member, determine if it's a property or field:

```
foreach (var member in type.GetMembers(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.GetField))
{
    if (member is FieldInfo fi)
    {

    }
    else if (member is PropertyInfo pi)
    {

    }
}
```

** If you want to find properties or fields you can *set*, you might need to change the binding flags.

Note that, from a design perspective, fields should probably be protected or private. To expose data from your class, you should ideally use properties. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295109/3181933).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, both classes have fields. So, you need to use `GetType().GetFields()`.

```
class Foo {
 public string propA;
 public Bar propB;
}

class Bar {
 public string propC;
}
```

If you want to use `GetType().GetProperties()`, then the classes become:

```
class Foo {
 private string _propA;
 public string PropA { get { return _propA; } set { _propA= value; } }

 private Bar _propB;
 public Bar PropB { get { return _propB; } set { _propB= value; } }
}

class Bar {
 public string propC;
}
```