# Getting data from panel (automation)

Tags: c#, winforms, ui-automation, teststack

I would like to know is possible that getting list/values from the panel.(bec. panel just panel)

This panel behavior is like gridview or listview. Have rows and columns but the control type is pane.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGL22.png)

I use automation tools, UIA and TestStack but in vain I find this panel I don't know how to get data from panel. This panel has no child elements/items.

Does anyone have any idea or what I'm looking for or this thing is impossible?

thankyou

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: sorry, i think winforms

Comment: what do you mean by its values? its properties?

Comment: Not the properties only row values. The targeting app has panels, each panel contains lots of values, name, type, etc. I want to export this values. Just the problem is this panel not a simple gridview from where easy to get values.

Comment: I think what you want is related to reflection, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class

Comment: If the _pane_ does show any child elements in the Automation Tree, then while it may appear as a grid control it is likely single owner drawn window that appears as a grid.  It needs to expose child elements that represent the cells for you to retrieve any values.