# LINQ Where clause from array of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of class Products:

```
class Products
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use one TextBox to search through any matching products utilizing a wildcard value.  This would return me a list of items where all values in the search string are found somewhere in the four properties listed above.

As of now, I'm using `string[] values = searchText.Split("*".ToCharArray)` to seperate the values of the search string into an array of strings (based on an asterisk wildcard).  From there, I get stumped, since I want to search for all values of the search string in all properties of the class.

I tried to figure it out using a complex LINQ statement, but I have not been able to figure it out how to make this work.  I don't know how to build a Where statement when I don't know how many values I'm going need to test against my four properties.

Comment: When you say "wildcard search", what would the input look like? What wildcard characters do you want to support? Also, when you say, *"all values in the search string"*, do you mean they may have more than one term they're searching for? Some sample input and expected output may be helpful.

Comment: What I'd like is to be able to accept a search value like "hem*per" and that would return items where both "hem" and "per" could be found anywhere in the four values of a given Product object.  This would return a product where the name could be "Hemerocallis" and the category could be "Perennial".

Comment: @LiquidDrummer - So, based on that description, you're not doing a "wildcard" search. You're simply using a `*` as a delimiter to break up the individual strings you're looking for.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Yes . . .  sorry, the wildcard verbiage is a bit misleading.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @LiquidDrummer - Am I right that you just want `*` to delimit your keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you're breaking search up into separate keywords, using `*` as the delimiter, which you've described in the comments, then this is how you do it:

```
var products = new List<Products>()
{
    new Products()
    {
        Name = "theo frederick smith",
        Size = "",
        ProductId = "",
        Category = "brown",
    }
};

var searchText = "fred*brown";

var splits = searchText.Split("*".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var results =
    products
        .Where(p => splits.All(s =>
            p.Name.Contains(s)
            || p.Size.Contains(s)
            || p.ProductId.Contains(s)
            || p.Category.Contains(s)));
```

That matches the input.

Alternatively, if you really want a wildcard search, such as `"fred*smith"` (meaning that any one field must contain `"fred"` followed by zero or more characters and followed by `"smith"`), then this works:

```
var products = new List<Products>()
{
    new Products()
    {
        Name = "theo frederick smith",
        Size = "",
        ProductId = "",
        Category = "brown",
    }
};

var searchText = "fred*smith";

var wildcard =
    new Regex(
        String.Join(".*",
            searchText
                .Split('*')
                .Select(x => Regex.Escape(x))));

var results =
    products
        .Where(p => new []
        {
            p.Name, p.Size, p.ProductId, p.Category
        }.Any(x => wildcard.IsMatch(x)));
```

Comment: @RufusL - Just some sample data. The first code block used it.

Answer (score 1):

Naively, you could write

```
products.Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(search) 
                  || x.Size.Contains(search) 
                  || x.ProductId.Contains(search) 
                  || x.Category.Contains(search))
```

You would be better off putting that logic in your `Product` class.

So you would have:

```
class Products
{
    public bool Contains(string term) {
              return Name.Contains(search) || Size.Contains(search) || 
              ProductId.Contains(search) || Category.Contains(search)
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

And then simply `products.Where(x=>x.Contains(search))`

You could also use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class) to get all the property names and do a for each on each `string` and check for `Contains`.

Comment: How does this handle the "wildcard" requirement?

Comment: It doesn't, when I wrote it, it just showed as delimited on a wildcard - so in that case, the author would have had to loop through each term until one was found.