# Loop through all the strings in an object with muliple kinds of properties

Tags: c#, oop

I currently have an object

```
user
```

this object has multiple propeties under which

```
user.id //(int)
user.firstName //(string)
user.lastName //(string)
user.phone //(int)
user.email //(string)
```

I want to apply a string method to all of the string in this object,
How do I loop trough these, so that all strings get effected, but not the ints?

I can of course manually check aplly the method to all string properties, but I'd prefer it if I could use an

```
foreach
```

loop.

Comment: while not 100% identical to your question, the dupe mentions reflection, which is what you need.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class