# Access Properties of a class at run time to read the values from

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a `class` like that: In reality it has around 350 fields

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string MiddleName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}
    public string Adrs1 {get;set;}
    public string Adrs2 {get;set;}
}
```

I call an external API that I can't change its code and it populates the results in those fields so the end result is a `List<MyClass>` with those fields populated.
**However** I want to then later get a new list with only "**some**" of those fiedls as the return result so that I can pass a parameter of `List<string> fieldsOfInterest` to that method and only get the results for those. Is there a way with maybe reflection to do this?
So let's say if my `fieldsOfInterest` params has only `"FirstName"` and `"LastName"` in it, then I just want those back.
How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried until now ? You can use `System.Linq` to group what you want with conditions.

Comment: @Little_Dev I have not been able to do anything.  I don't know.

Comment: @Little_Dev so for example we got a for-each(var item in results)  but then I know only to say item.FirstName,  item.LastName etc... but I want this to be dynamic from the list of properties I pass to it.

Comment: If you cannot use anything smarter, if you don't know the returned properties in advance, then you'll have to go with `Reflection`

Comment: @Marco yes I think I need Reflection but I don't know how to use it. Do you have a sample code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class

Comment: @Marco yes seen that thanks but I want to "access" those properties to read their values at runtime. So for example instead of item.FirstName : the FirstName part I want to build at run-time so I can pass different list of properties to it.

Comment: With Reflection you can read all the properties of a class with their values, at runtime!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve here. Want to execute specific logic when a given property is filled? Why don't you simply ignore the other properties if they are not set?

However you can access your variables with these two way, either by Reflection which will have more overhead for your task, but should not significantly slow your app down as today's hardware is usually sufficient, or by a switch-case. Both have their pro's and con's so you can select them to your needs or maybe someone comes up with an even better approach ;)

Anyway, here's your sample code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var myClass = new MyClass{FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar"};
    var fieldsOfInterest = new List<string>{"FirstName", "LastName"};
    GetPropertyValueWithReflection(myClass, fieldsOfInterest);
    Console.WriteLine("----------------");
    GetPropertyValueWithSwitch(myClass, fieldsOfInterest);
}

private static void GetPropertyValueWithReflection(MyClass myClass, IEnumerable<string> fieldsOfInterest)
{
    foreach (var fieldOfInterest in fieldsOfInterest)
    {
        var propOfMyClass = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(fieldOfInterest).GetValue(myClass, null);
        Console.WriteLine($"Value of property '{fieldOfInterest}': {propOfMyClass}");
    }
}

private static void GetPropertyValueWithSwitch(MyClass myClass, IEnumerable<string> fieldsOfInterest)
{
    foreach (var fieldOfInterest in fieldsOfInterest)
    {
        switch (fieldOfInterest)
        {
            case nameof(myClass.FirstName):
                Console.WriteLine($"Value of property '{fieldOfInterest}': {myClass.FirstName}");
                break;
            case nameof(myClass.LastName):
                Console.WriteLine($"Value of property '{fieldOfInterest}': {myClass.LastName}");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
Value of property 'FirstName': Foo
Value of property 'LastName': Bar
----------------
Value of property 'FirstName': Foo
Value of property 'LastName': Bar
```

Hint: It's just a sample code, and for example the switch-case requires more case-conditions in order to catch all properties of your class, but it should give you an idea how it's working ;)

Comment: I figured it out.  The link in the comments someone had posted does the job. All I had to add to it was to first check and see if the property I am for-each ing on is in the list of fields I care about or not.   I accepted your answer too but TBH didn't even read it lol but you had spent some good time and effort on it so I accepted it

Comment: Glad you could solve the problem. It doesn't matter who brings the right answer or comment, the main thing is that you could be helped ;) Thanks for accepting the answer anyway